# How do I enter the id manually, even though it is GenerationType.IDENTITY

Tags: spring-boot, resttemplate, spring-boot-test, spring-resttemplate

I want to enter a manual id so I can test, but even if I enter 7 it creates the id

I want my entity to be auto incrementing, but if I enter the value manually I get the manual value, but even if I insert the value manually it is getting the next value in the sequence.

I'm using spring-data

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
class BairroControllerTest {

    @BeforeAll
    @Transactional
    void inicializar() {

        Estado estadoTeste = new Estado(1L, "estado teste ", "uf");
        Cidade cidadeTeste = new Cidade(1L, "cidade teste", estadoTeste);
        Bairro bairroTeste = new Bairro(7L, "bairro teste", "logradouros", cidadeTeste);
        estadoRepository.save(estadoTeste);
        cidadeRepository.save(cidadeTeste);
        bairroRepository.save(bairroTeste);
    }
```

my class

```
@Table(name = "tb_bairro")
@Entity(name = "Bairro")
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = "id")
public class Bairro {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
```

I tried using sequence, auto and create setId